# How to Use multi+shift on Server-Side Datatable?

Tags: datatables

Datatables allows you to use shift+select, while also allowing you to select single items without losing previously selected items by having the select style set to multi+shift.

```
'select': {style': 'multi+shift'}
```

However, for this datatable, that doesn't seem to work at all. What am I missing?

```
var $testTable = $("#test-list").DataTable({
    "dom": '<"dataTables_top"i<"dataTables_custom_buttons">f>rt'+ '<"dataTables_bottom"ilp>',
    "autoWidth": false,
    "lengthChange": 100,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 100, 200, 500, 1000], [10, 25, 100, 200, 500, 1000]],
    "paging": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "stripeClasses": [ 'odd', 'even' ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": '<h3>Test...</h3>',
        "search" : '',
        "sLengthMenu" : "_MENU_ Per Page",
        "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_",
        paginate: {
            first: '<i class="fad fa-step-backward"></i>',
            previous: '<i class="fad fa-backward"></i>',
            next: '<i class="fad fa-forward"></i>',
            last: '<i class="fad fa-step-forward"></i>'
        }
    },
    'select': 'multi+shift',
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-11], 
            'searchable': false
        },
        {
            "targets": 'no-sort',
            "orderable": false,
        },
        {
            "targets": [8,11],
            "visible": false
        },
        {
            "iDataSort": 8,
            "aTargets" : [7]
        },
        {
            "iDataSort": 11,
            "aTargets" : [10]
        },
        {
            "targets": -1,
            'searchable': false
        }
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
       ......
    },
    "drawCallback": function(settings) {
        ......
    }
});
```